# Magento 2.2 login user by given id

Tags: module, magento2.2, login

I have a flow where I need to verify if user has verified their phone number, if not I have redirected them to verification page in my module, once the user verify their OTP sent to their number I need to auto login user, likewise it is done in the case of email verification, once user click to verification code they are auto logged in into their account

Comment: what issue you are facing, where you are stuck ?

Comment: Dont find anywhere how to di that, that is why I didnt share any code, since I dont have any code yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this blog to see how you can login using customer id, it is very useful

http://www.zexperto.com/magento/log-by-customer-id

```
$customer_id = 1;
$objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customer_id);
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Comment: Using Object Manager directly doesn't follow Magento best practice.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh but `$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);` is it a good way to go? I mean will it do what is required and magento will allow when I publish my plugin with magento?

Comment: @riksof-zeeshan Not check yet. But, I think `setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);` is the key.

Comment: Yes @KhoaTruongDinh, I agree with you , but this is an example of how to login by customer id, the object Manager  should be initialize in the constructor, as well the Customer. Thank you for clarify this point